# creating shell script with contents

Tags: bash, shell

How does one create a shell script that creates a file with a whole bunch of contents. I currently have this and it does not seem to be working well. Any cleaner approach is also welcomed.

```
echo "Enter 1 to generate View"
echo "Enter 2 to generate Model and View"
echo "Enter 3 to generate View, Model and Template"

while true; do
read -p "Please select an option: " option
read -p "Please enter the name of the class you wold like to genrate: " class
case $option in
    1 ) 
        FILE="views/$class"
        /bin/cat <<EOM >$FILE
            some content        
        EOM
        break;;
    2 ) 
        exit;;
    3 ) 
        exit;;
    * ) 
        echo "Enter 1 to generate View"
        echo "Enter 2 to generate Model and View"
        echo "Enter 3 to generate View, Model and Template";;
esac
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second `EOM` should be at the beginning of a line, or use

```
 # code
    cat<<-EOM
    ...
    EOM
```

So here :

```
    /bin/cat <<EOM >$FILE
some content        
EOM
```

Note :

like [barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) said, if you use `<<-EOM`, use tabs not spaces.

Comment: Note that when use use `<<-EOM`, the indentation before `EOM` **must** be TABs, not spaces.